# How to convert an Array to an Array of Objects in JS & React using "react-select"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have an Array with some Elements:

```js
ArrayE = ["Car", "Bike", "Bus", "Truck"]
```

I have to make an array like this:

```js
ArrayX = [
    { value: "Car", label: "Car" },
    { value: "Bike", label: "Bike" },
    { value: "Bus", label: "Bus" },
    { value: "Truck", label: "Truck" }
];
```

How can I convert the first Array to the second one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript map method to achieve this.

```js
let ArrayE = ["Car","Bike","Bus","Truck"]

let ArrayX = ArrayE.map( el => ({'value':el,'label':el}))

console.log(ArrayX)
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can use javascript forEach method like below...**

```
function myFuc(arr) {
    const result = [];
    arr.forEach(el => {
        result.push({
            value: el,
            label: el
        })
    }); 
    return result;
}
```